# Is it possible to deny access to domains that link using specific anchor text (using .htaccess / or something else)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess -- is it possible to deny access to a website that uses a specific anchor text to link to your website?

Assume a bad website: SomeBadWebsite.org/hate.php posted a link to my website using the anchor text: 'I Hate You'. So the code used on SomeBadWebsite.org/hate.php to link to my site is:

```
<a href="http://MyWebsite.com">I Hate You</a>
```

---

NOTES:

- Please note that I only need to block this specific anchor text (I Hate You) and if the same SomeBadWebsite.org links to my website using any other anchor text, the link should not be denied.
- It would be best when the anchor text ignores capitalization (ie. I Hate You = i HATE you etc.).

I think .htaccess could/should use RewriteCond and HTTP_REFERER + something to check for the specific anchor text -- but I don't know the exact code.

ADDED:

If it's not possible using .htaccess - is there any other good and easy way to achieve the goal?

Comment: no, its not possible,  but why - sounds more than a little control frek'ish

Comment: It's to prevent bad domains from trying to sabotage your website (by linking using adult or gambling keywords, for example).

Comment: i dont see what the text link matters - google is not going to use it (if you somehow thought they did)

Comment: Anchor text in a link matters a lot in SEO (it's common for attackers to use adult or gambling anchor text to dilute your website's theme).

Comment: "Anchor text is weighted (ranked) highly in search engine algorithms, because the linked text is usually relevant to the landing page." 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_text

Comment: which says nothing about your basic argument that other sites can adversely effect your ranking by the text they use in a a link  to you. - any how to your question you cant. and it wouldn't matter if you could; if goggle bot was using data from another site, how your sited treated the link would not affect how the google algorithm did

Comment: You may look up the term 'negative SEO' and there are many examples of webmasters dealing with adverse effects of low-quality links pointed to their websites without their knowledge or consent. But that's a different subject.

Comment: google "There’s almost nothing a competitor can do to harm your ranking or have your site removed from our index" - now go build the best darn cat blog in the universe

Comment: The above phrase is outdated. In 2012 Google removed this sentence and changed it to: 'Google works hard to prevent other webmasters from being able to harm your ranking or have your site removed from our index.' - you may Google it. 
But again, it's not the subject of the discussion.

Comment: you cant, and it wouldn't effect google if you could -that's on topic

Comment: Just an idea - you could use a server side scripting language to check for the referrer header, download the referring webpage and check for any links back to your website and then retrieve the link's text.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. htaccess has no method to access, read and understand any link text on any web page.

Answer (score 0):

Only the URL will be passed to your website, while the text part (I Hate You) won't.

So basically you cannot distinguish between 'I Hate You' or 'Rabbit'.

Comment: and then only sometimes, and then it may or may not be the actual url